# NoFlo Error: TypeError: Object #<Port/ArrayPort> has no method 'isAddressable'

Tags: javascript, node.js, noflo

I recently started getting the errors:

`TypeError: Object #<Port> has no method 'isAddressable'`

`TypeError: Object #<ArrayPort> has no method 'isAddressable'`

I am creating the ports on my components like:

```
this.inPorts.in = new noflo.Port();
```

Comment: I'm researching whether this is related to a change in how ports can be added via the `add` method on `inPorts` and `outPorts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have NoFlo 0.4 or older somewhere in the mix.

the `isAddressable` method was added in 0.5.

Look at `npm list` to see what packages you have installed an older, incompatible version of NoFlo.

Comment: Thank you again, bergie.  I had checked `npm list` from all of my module folders, but I had one module that referenced another module that still contained a 0.4.5 reference from within it's node_modules folder. Example: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9a61d411f0d4c5db859f