# noflo 0.5.13 spreadsheet example broken?

Tags: noflo

I am new to noflo and looking at examples in order to explore it. The [spreadsheet](https://github.com/noflo/noflo/blob/master/examples/spreadsheet/parse.fbp) example looked interesting but I couldn't make it run. First, it takes some time and manual debugging to identify missing components, not a big deal and I believe will be improved in the future, for now the error message I get is

```
return process.component.outPorts[port].attach(socket);
                                          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Apparently, before this isAddressable() was also undefined. Checked with this [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295978/noflo-error-typeerror-object-port-arrayport-has-no-method-isaddressable) but I don't have any noflo 0.4 as a dependency anywhere. Spent some time to debug it but seemingly stuck at it, decided to post to SO.

**The question is, what are the correct steps to run the spreadsheet example?**

For reproduction, here is what I have done:

0) install the following components

```
noflo-adapters
noflo-core
noflo-couchdb
noflo-filesystem
noflo-groups
noflo-objects
noflo-packets
noflo-strings
noflo-tika
noflo-xml
```

i) edit spreadsheet/parse.fbp, because first error was

```
throw new Error("No outport '" + port + "' defined in process " + proc
          ^
Error: No outport 'error' defined in process Read (Read() ERROR -> IN Display())
```

apparently couchdb ReadDocument component does not provide Error outport. therefore replaced ReadDocument with ReadFile.

```
18c18
< 'tika-app-0.9.jar' -> TIKA Read(ReadDocument)
---
> 'tika-app-0.9.jar' -> TIKA Read(ReadFile)
```

ii) at this point, received the following:

```
if (process.component.outPorts[port].isAddressable()) {
                                       ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

and improvised a stunt by checking if isAddressable is defined at this location of code:

```
@@ -259,9 +261,11 @@
     throw new Error("No outport '" + port + "' defined in process " + process.id + " (" + (socket.getId()) + ")");
     return;
   }
-      if (process.component.outPorts[port].isAddressable()) {
+      if (process.component.outPorts[port].isAddressable && process.component.outPorts[port].isAddressable()) {
     return process.component.outPorts[port].attach(socket, index);
   }
   return process.component.outPorts[port].attach(socket);
 };
```

and either way fails. Again, the question is **What are the correct steps to run the spreadsheet example?**

Thanks in advance.